# Is it possible to depend expected calls in gMock together?

Tags: c++, googletest

Assume that I want to test following function:

```cpp
template<typename Pack>
bool is_valid(const Pack& pack) {
  if (pack.a() > 0)
    return pack.b();
  return false;
};
```

I will write a small mocker for `Pack` as follows:

```
class PackMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, a, (), (const));
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, b, (), (const));
};
```

and now I try to write test this method with in test function:

```
TEST(MyTests, IsValidTest) {
    PackMock p;
    EXPECT_CALL(p, a())
        .WillOnce(Return(0))
        .WillOnce(Return(1))
        .WillOnce(Return(20));
    EXPECT_CALL(p, b())
        .WillOnce(Return(true))
        .WillOnce(Return(false))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));

    EXPECT_FALSE(is_valid(p));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_valid(p));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_valid(p));
}
```

At the first sight, this code should be OK. I have 3 expectation and my mocker returns 3 different set of values and this is what happens in real application running (data-wise).

But if you run this code, you will get error that mocker expectations is not satisfied (it says that `b()` is expected to call 3 times while it is called twice). The reason is that when first test happens, `a()` returns `0`, and because of `if` condition, `b()` is not called at all. So at the end, everything is messed up.

Now I wonder if there is a way to for example connect these expectations together or I should always set my expectations based on how code works rather than how my data works? I personally think that the later should be correct. For example, if `a()` in mocker called we make sure that at we always satisfy 1 expectation in `b()`? or for example we chain these expectations together in a way that `b()` is expected only if `a() > 0`?

Comment: proper solution is to test each call of `is_valid` in separate test case.

Comment: I would add to the first comment, you are trying to test the implementation, that is not unit tests are for. Use two test cases, one is for unraised b calls, and another one is for raised b calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can use a `testing::Sequence` instance to keep track of mock calls in sequence. You can also directly define a `InSequence` for the test as in the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#ordered-vs-unordered-calls-orderedcalls).

Secondly, your first `EXPECT_CALL` does not call the `b()` mock call, because `a()` returns `0` which then never evaluates the `return pack.b()`.

As an example found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hcY47q6rj), I've indicated how you can use a `Sequence` class in your example as follows:

```cpp
TEST(MyTests, IsValidTest) {
    
    // Setup the mock object
    PackMock p;

    // Keep track of the sequence of events 
    // using a sequence class
    testing::Sequence sequence;

    // # First is_valid() - a
    EXPECT_CALL(p, a())
        .InSequence(sequence)
        .WillOnce(Return(0));

    // # First is_valid() - b - not called
    // EXPECT_CALL(p, b())
    //     .InSequence(sequence)
    //     .WillOnce(Return(true));

    // # Second is_valid() - a
    EXPECT_CALL(p, a())
        .InSequence(sequence)
        .WillOnce(Return(1));

    // # Second is_valid() - b
    EXPECT_CALL(p, b())
        .InSequence(sequence)
        .WillOnce(Return(false));
        
    // # Third is_valid() - a
    EXPECT_CALL(p, a())
        .InSequence(sequence)
        .WillOnce(Return(20));

    // # Third is_valid() - b
    EXPECT_CALL(p, b())
        .InSequence(sequence)
        .WillOnce(Return(true));

    // Act - Initiate the calls and inject the 
    // mock object as a dependency
    
    // # First call - a() returns 0, 
    // thus returns false (but() b is not called)
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_valid(p));
    
    // # Second call - a() returns 1, 
    // thus returns false, because b returns false
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_valid(p));

    // # Third call - a() returns 20, 
    // thus returns true, because b returns true
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_valid(p));
}
```

This will provide the following output:

```
Running main() from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/googletest/release-1.10.0/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyTests
[ RUN      ] MyTests.IsValidTest
[       OK ] MyTests.IsValidTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyTests (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Thus, to answer your question:

> Is it possible to depend expected calls in gMock together?

**Yes, using a `testing::Sequence` class with or just using `testing::InSequence()`**

Thus, if you have calls depending on each other in your test, use a sequence class instance(s) to link them.